# Passing multiple values as parameter to mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a database, and I want to get the names of multiple users in the same query by passing in an array of user_ids. Sadly, I cannot get this to work.

I have this query:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT name FROM users WHERE user_id=?');
```

Where the parameter is an array:

```
$stmt->bind_param('i', $user_ids);
```

The `user_ids` array looks like this `{1, 2}`. Basically, I want to get the name of user 1 and user 2, without having to query the database more than one time.

When I have this code, I only seem to get the name of the first user, not the others:

```
$stmt->bind_result($name);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    array_push($names, $name);
}
```

Keep in mind that I have initialized `$names` like this `$names = array();`

How could I solve this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `IN` statement like this :

```
<?php
//Your array
$user_ids= array(1, 2);

$inQuery = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));

$db = new PDO(...);
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT name FROM users WHERE user_id IN(' . $inQuery . ')');

// bindvalue is 1-indexed, so $k+1
foreach ($user_ids as $k => $id)
    $stmt->bindValue(($k+1), $id);

$stmt->execute();
```

Inspired by [Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

---

From the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement using an array of values for an IN clause */
$params = array(1, 21, 63, 171);
/* Create a string for the parameter placeholders filled to the number of params */
$place_holders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($params), '?'));

/*
    This prepares the statement with enough unnamed placeholders for every value
    in our $params array. The values of the $params array are then bound to the
    placeholders in the prepared statement when the statement is executed.
    This is not the same thing as using PDOStatement::bindParam() since this
    requires a reference to the variable. PDOStatement::execute() only binds
    by value instead.
*/
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM contacts WHERE id IN ($place_holders)");
$sth->execute($params);
?>
```

Comment: You don't have to bind the params with the `foreach`, You can just use `$stmt->execute($user_ids);`

Comment: When I bind the parameters in `$stmt->execute($user_ids)` I get this error **mysqli_stmt::execute() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given**

Comment: @Alekplay, try the approach first and echo $inQuery, you should see "?,?" to declare that 2 parameters are expected.